# Select Multiple Rows Based On Common Column Value Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by, having

I have a User table say like:

| ID | Name | Ref_ID | Active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 100 | 1 |
| 2 | BCD | 200 | 0 |
| 3 | CDE | 300 | 1 |
| 4 | DEF | 300 | 0 |
| 5 | EFG | 300 | 1 |
| 6 | FGH | 400 | 0 |
| 7 | GHI | 400 | 0 |
| 8 | HIJ | 500 | 1 |
| 9 | IJK | 500 | 1 |

I want to find IDs and Names of those users who are **all inactive** under the same Ref_ID.
What I mean to say is, say for example there are 3 users with Ref_ID = 300 and not all of them are inactive, so I won't want those users in the result. For users with Ref_ID = 400, all users inactive, hence I want them in the result set.
I am trying to achieve a result similar to this:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | BCD |
| 6 | FGH |
| 7 | GHI |

How can I achieve this? I have tried using group by and inner join queries but not able to get them right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.ref_id = t.ref_id and t2.active = 1
                 );
```

Or window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(active) over (partition by ref_id) as max_active
      from t
     ) t
where max_active = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT ID, Name
FROM yourTable
WHERE Ref_ID IN (SELECT Ref_ID
                 FROM yourTable
                 GROUP BY Ref_ID
                 HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Active = 1 THEN 1 END) = 0);
```